# access EditText text by method from custom dialog class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this custom alertDialog class and I defined a setText() method to set EditText text:

```
public class CustomEditDialog extends AlertDialog {

private Context context;
private CustomEditText editTextTv;
private CustomTextView titleTv;

public CustomEditDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public CustomEditDialog(Context context, int themeResId) {
    super(context, themeResId);
    this.context = context;
}

protected CustomEditDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editbox_dialog_layout);

    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

    titleTv = (CustomTextView)findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
    editTextTv = (CustomEditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_et);


}


public void setText(CharSequence text){
    editTextTv.setText(text);
}

public String getText(){
    return editTextTv.getText().toString();
}


 }
```

Now when I use my CustomEditDialog in activity and access setText() method to populate edittext:

```
CustomEditDialog customEditDialog = new CustomEditDialog(context);
                customEditDialog.setText("OK!!");
                customEditDialog.show();
```

I get this error:

```
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.k.kh.CustomEditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Please help me.

Comment: Call `customEditDialog.show()` before `settext()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you are trying to call editTextTv.setText() before creating it. 
To fix it you have to call .show() first to invoke onCreate() and initialize CustomEditDialog view:

```
CustomEditDialog customEditDialog = new CustomEditDialog(context);
            customEditDialog.show();
            customEditDialog.setText("OK!!");
```